# How many terms are there containing the term $xyk^2$ in the expansion of $(2x-y+t+3z+4k)^8$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, binomial-theorem, multinomial-coefficients

> How many terms are there containing the term $xyk^2$ in the expansion of $(2x-y+t+3z+4k)^8$ such as $xyk^2t^2z^2$ or $xyk^2t^4z^0$ or $xyk^2z^3t$ etc.

I made up this question and calculated it , but i do not know whether my solution is correct or not.

$\color{blue}{Solution:}$

$\color{red}{1-)}$ I turned it out to be binomial expression such that $\color{green}{a=}2x-y+4k$ and $\color{green}{b=}t+3z$ , so I will work over $(a+b)^8$.

$\color{red}{2-)}$ I thought that i should look for  $xyk^2$ in $a$  ,so i said that the exponential of $a$ must be $4$ , because $1+1+2=4$  which are the sum of the exponents of  $xyk^2$.

$\color{red}{3-)}$ Hence, the exponent of $b$ must be $4$ ,as well. Because the sum of the exponents of $a$ and $b$ must be equal to $8$.

$\color{red}{4-)}$ Therefore, the terms which contains $xyk^2$ in the expansion of $(2x-y+t+3z+4k)^8$ must be equal the numbers of terms in the expansion of $b$ ,i.e, $(3z+t)^4$. It is equal to $5$

So , my answer is $5$ . I checked it with second solution. However , i am not sure about the truth of the first way. Is my first way true?

Thanks for all contributions..

$\color{blue}{Solution 2:}$ Because of the fact that the sum of the exponents must be equal to $8$ , i should find the number of partition of $4$ in two part so as to find the number of combinations of the exponents of $t$ and $z$. Then, $t=4,z=0$ or $t=3,z=1$ or $t=2,z=2$ or $t=1,z=3$ or $t=0,z=4$

Comment: I assume that by "containing" you mean divisible. Is that right? When you count, are you supposed to consider coefficients as multiplicities or not? For example, in $(1+x)^2=1+2x+x^2$, do you count $2$ terms containing $x$, or $3=2+1$?

Comment: So your terms should be in the form of $xyk^2t^az^b$ where $a+b=4$ and $a,b$ are in the set $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: @Soheil you wrote it when i was editing :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both solutions are correct. The reasoning to obtain $5$ in the first solution is somewhat more detailed. The essence is in both solutions the same, namely to keep the focus on the number of different terms in the expansion of $(t+3z)^4$.

Here is a crosscheck (kinda overkill). We use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[x^k](ax+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}a^kz^{n-k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain by successively applying (1)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[xyk^2]}&\color{blue}{(2x-y+t+3z+4k)^8}\\
> &=\binom{8}{1}2^1[yk^2](-y+t+3z+4k)^7\\
> &=\binom{8}{1}2^1\binom{7}{1}(-1)^1[k^2](t+3z+4k)^6\\
> &=\binom{8}{1}2^1\binom{7}{1}(-1)^1\binom{6}{2}4^2(t+3z)^4\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=-26\,880(t+3z)^4}\\
> \end{align*}
> The number of wanted terms is the number of different terms of $(t+3z)^4$ expanded, which is $5$.

Comment: wow ,thank you very much.By the way , is my thinking way correct in the first solution. I meant  can the other types of question  be solved like in first solution

Comment: @Bulbasaur: Your arguments are sound. I've added a corresponding statement in my answer. Regards,